# how to integrate in the diagonal?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, area, volume, transformation

Imagine we have a function f(x,y). For simplicity, let's say:

$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
c & \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq 1 \text{ and } 0 \leq y \leq 1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

With so much imagination, think this is the function:
[image]
I know how to integrate with respect to x, and how to integrate with respect to y. But what if I want to integrate with respect to a different direction? In example the diagonal? How do I transform the function so that I can have something as:

[image]

I would expect the result of the integral (with respect to our 'new x') to be a function:
[image]

I need it specially for distributions, but I assume the concept is the same.

Sorry for my being so naive, but I didn't even know how to ask for this in google.

Comment: You need to change from your original two variables to a new pair, which might use one of the old variables. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) is how. For example, if your diagonal holds constant $u=ax+by$, make $u$ one of the new integration variables.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It looks like the transformation I am looking for is $(x', y') = \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}(x - y)}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{2}(x + y)}{2}\right)$ which corresponds to a rotation of 45 degrees. 

Follow up question is, how do I deal with the boundaries? Do I have to find the equation of the pair of lines below and above?